Find another instance to process kafka message
I have 2 SpringBoot applications deployed in AWS, APP1 is managing cars and for each new added car, it will create 2 kafka topics to be used only for that car(topic A for events APP1 -> APP2 and topic B for events APP2 -> APP1).
After they are created APP1 will send an event to APP2 to start processing that car (continuous async task) and from time to time APP2 will also send some events on the car's topic back to APP1 to signal some events on that car. Since at some point APP2 will run out of capacity I will have an extra instance of it, but I am not sure what is the best way to manage the communication APP1 -> APP2 with multiple APP2 instances that have capacity (because at some point the very crowded instance may become less crowded).
Because if I have all the instances in the same consumer group only one will receive the message to start processing the car, but if it does not have the capacity, how can I find another instance to do the task?
Another idea that I'm thinking of is when I send an event from APP1, to have instances of APP2 in different  consumer groups so each instance will receive the event to start the processing car, but how to make sure only one of them is processing it?
EDIT: added code
What I have so far:
creating the car's 2 topics when it gets created in APP1
  public void createCarTopics(String carName) {
    try (AdminClient adminClient = AdminClient.create(kafkaAdmin.getConfigurationProperties())) {
        String controlTopic = carName + "_control";
        String detectionTopic = carName + "_detection";
        int partitions = 1;

        adminClient.createTopics(Arrays.asList(
                new NewTopic(controlTopic, partitions, replicationFactor),
                new NewTopic(detectionTopic, partitions, replicationFactor)
        ));
    }
}


@Service
public class KafkaProducerImpl implements KafkaProducer {

    private final KafkaTemplate<String, CarControlEvent> kafkaTemplate;

    @Override
    public void sendCarControlEvent(CarControlEvent event) {
        String carTopic = event.getCarName() + "_control"; // Single topic per car for APP11 -> APP2 communication
        kafkaTemplate.send(carTopic, event);
    }
}


And inside APP2 I listen like this
@KafkaListener(topics = "#{@kafkaConsumerConfig.controlTopicForCar('carName')}", groupId = "${spring.kafka.consumer.group-id}")
public void listenCarControl(String messageEvent) {
    try {
        CarControlEvent event = objectMapper.readValue(messageEvent, CarControlEvent.class);

        switch (event.getActionType()) {
            case START_CAR_PROCESSING:
                startCar(event);
                break;
            case STOP_CAR_PROCESSING:
                stopCar(event);
                break;
        }
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
    }
}


@Component
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    public String controlTopicForCar(String carName) {
        return carName + "_control";
    }

    public String detectionTopicForCar(String carName) {
        return carName + "_detection";
    }
}

In this approach I have a single partition and all consumers in the same group, so when having multiple instances we get the control messages into a single consumer. But the problem is what happens if I dont have processing capacity into that instance and we have to look for another instance?
I am open to other implementation strategy if there is something to help me process cars into multiple instances.


Please show your code as as a [mcve] 2. A "topic per entity" model is generally an anti pattern. Why can't you have a "cars topic" with many partitions?


@OneCricketeer added code

@OneCricketeer If I have a single topic with many partitions, let's say we have 2 instances of APP2, and I send a message for a new car or it's own partition. The instance that is full subscribed to that partition and receives the message. We cant handle that extra car. How do we pass it to the other instance?

2 instances in the same consumer group will never share consumption of a partition. So two events for the same car would be handled by the same instance. If you need to "pass to the other instance", then you would need some regular RPC call outside of Kafka... e.g. RestTemplate, gRPC, etc. But Kafka defaults to batch 500 records at a time while consuming, so probably shouldn't be passing off secondary events, anyway

you need a Load Balancing Strategy when dealing with mass events .
in your case :
In APP1 when sending a new car processing request
// First, check available capacity
CompletableFuture<String> targetInstanceId = findAvailableInstance();

// Then send the processing request with the selected instance
CarProcessingRequest request = new CarProcessingRequest(
    carId,
    targetInstanceId,
    timestamp
);
kafkaTemplate.send(carTopicA, request);
}

In APP2 instances
@KafkaListener(topics = "#{carTopicA}")
public void handleCarProcessing(CarProcessingRequest request) {
    // Each instance checks if it's the target
    if (!request.targetInstanceId.equals(instanceId)) {
        return; // Ignore if not targeted
    }

    if (!hasCapacity()) {
        // Publish capacity issue
        publishCapacityUpdate();
        return;
    }

    // Process the car
    startCarProcessing(request.carId);
}

// Periodic capacity reporting in APP2
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 30000) // Every 30 seconds
public void reportCapacity() {
    InstanceCapacity capacity = new InstanceCapacity(
        instanceId,
        getCurrentLoad(),
        getAvailableSlots(),
        timestamp
    );
    kafkaTemplate.send("app2-capacity-topic", capacity);
}

** Edit **
to be more accurate ,Instead of creating separate topics per car, use a single topic for all car processing requests
The key for each message will be the car ID

APP1 Responsibilities:
When a new car is registered, APP1 publishes a message to the car processing topic with the car ID as the key
APP1 does not need to know or select the target APP2 instance
APP2 Responsibilities:
Each APP2 instance subscribes to the car processing topic using a unique consumer group.
When a message arrives, each instance checks if it has capacity to process the car
If an instance has capacity, it processes the car
If an instance does not have capacity, it publishes a "capacity full" event to a separate topic.

Capacity Management:

Each APP2 instance periodically publishes its current capacity metrics to a separate topic.
APP1 subscribes to this capacity topic and maintains a cache of instance capacities.

Instance Selection:

When a car processing message arrives, APP1 checks its capacity cache to find an available APP2 instance,
If all instances are at capacity, APP1 can retry the message later or send a notification.

Failover Handling:

If an APP2 instance fails to process a car, it can be retried by another instance.
APP1 can monitor the "capacity full" topic for instances that are overloaded and avoid sending new requests to them.

Can you explain this in more detail? Kafka doesn't exactly do "load balancing". Keyed events will always arrive in the same partition
